# Cannot install package "eventstudy" into Python - any ideas?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.9

essentially I'm currently trying to conduct an event study. I've found a neat package called "eventstudy" for Python which I haven't used yet at all.

The package and the installation is explained here:
https://lemairejean-baptiste.github.io/eventstudy/index.html

Seems super easy, however, I cannot get the package installed. First, I assumed it works like R and typed in import eventstudy as es in PyCharm. -> no module found

I've somehow understood that you need pip and use the terminal instead of PyCharm? I installed pip3 via the Mac OS Terminal. Now, I tried (in terminal and PyCharm) $pip install eventstudy and $pip3 install eventstudy but it first failed with some super long error and now continually says "installing building dependencies".

When going back to PyCharm, I again typed in import eventstudy as es without success.

I'm a little confused and would simply ask you guys if you can help an absolute newbie. I also wondered if the eventstudy package is somehow not downloadable/ installable?

Thanks!

/EDIT:

I've tried to install eventstudies via PyCharm directly (added the package in there directly, I showed a ton of error messages during installing but somehow downloaded and installed it successfully, now there's the same issue with numply, I'm getting a super long error message:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.20.1.zip (7.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.20.0.zip (8.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.19.5.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.19.4.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.19.1.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.19.0.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.18.5.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.18.4.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.18.3.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.18.2.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.18.1.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.18.0.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
  Using cached numpy-1.17.5.zip (6.4 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: numpy
    Running setup.py install for numpy: started
    Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/bin/python /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/tmpwfiinac7
         cwd: /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738
    Complete output (229 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:485: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Cythonizing sources
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c
        define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9
    creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy
    creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable xlf90
    Could not locate executable xlf
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable pgfortran
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-uzfzx9da/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-uzfzx9da/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-uzfzx9da/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 513, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 505, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-uzfzx9da/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-uzfzx9da/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 31, in run
        egg_info.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 24, in run
        self.run_command("build_src")
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_263690d43260436b9d332ec15da8e738/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 676, in get_mathlib_info
        raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/48/f445be426ccd9b2fb64155ac6730c7212358882e589cd3717477d739d9ff/numpy-1.20.1.zip#sha256=3bc63486a870294683980d76ec1e3efc786295ae00128f9ea38e2c6e74d5a60a (from https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/bin/python /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/tmpwfiinac7 Check the logs for full command output.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/bin/python /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/tmpn7yyl1rn
         cwd: /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_c181070de12e4f20bb1b0c6d4fbf5e19
    Complete output (229 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:485: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Cythonizing sources
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_c181070de12e4f20bb1b0c6d4fbf5e19/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_c181070de12e4f20bb1b0c6d4fbf5e19/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_c181070de12e4f20bb1b0c6d4fbf5e19/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/Users/constantin/PycharmProjects/EventStudy/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/fr/3xrgrwbd44vf58dqqtcml67h0000gn/T/pip-install-g1yxob_p/numpy_c181070de12e4f20bb1b0c6d4fbf5e19/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

... (had to delete 3/4)
```

I have no idea what's the issue here to be honest, sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: Can you post the error specifically

Comment: Hi Gabe, I just did (now for numpy as the eventstudy package magically installed after 10+ min)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow and Python. While you are new, it is encouraged for you to provide a more detailed question, such as attaching the picture of error message or a code block for it.

Anyhow, I assume you may be new to PyCharm as well.

Note that what I provide here is based on Wins 10 x64bit version:

First of all, you can install packages through PyCharm by using Alt+F12 (No sure about MacOS) OR click at the terminal tab below.

[image]

Second, just type `pip install eventstudy`

It will begin the installation shortly.

Once it finished installing the package along with any necessary dependencies, it will  notify you. Example:

```
Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 eventstudy-0.1a10 kiwisolver-1.3.1 matplotlib-3.3.4 pandas-1.2.3 patsy-0.5.1 pyparsing-2.4.7 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2021.1 scipy-1.6.1 six-1.15.0 statsmodels-0.12.2
```

Once you seen the message above, you will be able to use the package in pycharm via import function:

[image]

Comment: Thanks seraph for your reply. Unfortunately, I get a ton of error messages. Initially for the eventstudy package itself, now for numpy. I've uploaded the error message, do you have an idea? Could it might be the issue with different versions (I have read some stuff about it without understanding it)  Thanks!

Comment: I suspect it might be problems with your python version. You could try removing python cleanly, and reinstalling. You can also attempt this: first, pip install cython, then:
git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git

Comment: then do this: cd numpy, python setup.py build, python setup.py install

Comment: did any of the solution here worked? including gabe's?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a tutorial on pip](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/). This will teach you everything you need to know about the basics of using pip. However, this is a bit weird of an error and it's not perfectly evident as to why. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808698/python-pip-doesnt-build-dependencies-during-installation) SO post seems to deal with a similar issue, where pip is having build time issues with dependencies. Based on the linked post, I'd try doing

`pip install eventstudy --no-cache-dir`

As that's kind of what it looks like is happening to a degree.